# Traceability matrix in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Is there any best practise to realize a [Traceability Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceability_matrix) in TFS?

We are currently struggeling how we shall configure the Areas, Iterations and how we can build up the "matrix".
We are planning to use the Areas as "functional components" and the Iterations for the software releases.

At the end we want to be able to create a report like this:

```
                   | Release_1 | Release_2 | Release_3
-------------------------------------------------------
Requirement 1      |    X           X
Requirement 2      |                            X
Requirement 3      |    X                       X
```

The important point for us is to generate the complete requirement list for a specific release.
The problem we face is that the releases are developed incremental. Meaning over time new requirements are added. We are know looking for a simple way to also link the old/existing requirement to a specific release without the need for duplicating each requirement.

Can someone suggest a way to achive the above matrix?

EDIT:

Requirement means the functionality to be implemented. Release is a specific software version. The requirements are incrementally added to the releases. This means the number of implemented requirements may grow from release to release. What we can do now is to link the implementation of a requirement to a specific release (Iteration). But all the following releases (Iterations) automatically include this requirement, because we work incrementally. But it might also be possible that a requirement gets changed or even obsolete in a following release. How can we handle this to be able to get get the complete/full requirement list for a specific release?

Comment: It seems that the requirements are not being fully delivered in a single release, instead they are incrementally delivered over one or more releases (please correct me if I'm wrong). Can you define, in more depth, what you define a _Requirement_ and a _Release_ to be?